# Editing Plex database, edit rows that match a certain criteria

Tags: database, sqlite, plex

I need to change the file name of my media to include a tag at the end of the file name. My issue is how do I target specific file paths to add something to the end of a mkv file name inside the database?

Example:
Folder path:
tv/show1/season01/My Episode s01e01.mkv

I want to search the database for all media located at tv/show1/season01 and add [DB1] at the end of the filename(before the extension obviously).

So the result would be:
Search database for all media located at “tv/show1/season01/“ then add [DB1] at the end of the file name.

So tv/show1/season01/My Episode s01e01.mkv becomes tv/show1/season01/My Episode s01e01 [DB1].mkv

I have been able to successfully mass change the file path and can do a mass change of the end of the file name for everything that ends in .mkv, however not every media file will end in [DB1]. I need some files to end in [DB2] etc… so that’s why I need to be able to target a root file path then change all media in that folder that is a .mkv field.